# Changing background image bootstrap nav-pills

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been asked by a friend to create a website.
I've used bootstrap 3 as a framework for the website and have hit a bit of a stumbling block.

My friend wanted a tabbed section where the background image of the section changes depending on which tab is active. I've been able to make it work for just the tab-pane using css, but I need to be able to change the entire section background and not just the tab pane.

I think it will require some JavaScript, but unfortunately my skills in that area a still a bit too weak to know how to do this, and google has been about as helpful as a hole in the head.

below is the section of html that i need the background image to change with each tab

```
<section id="about" class="content-section text-center">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="tab-content vertical-center">
      <div id="aboutus" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h2>...</h2>
        <p>...</p>
      </div>

      <div id="history" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h2>...</h2>
        <p>...</p>
      </div>

      <div id="chef" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h2>...</h2>
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 nav-pills-bg">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
      <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#aboutus">...</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#history">...</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#chef">...</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: can you add code in jsfiddle?

Comment: So you haven't made any attempt of your own... why should we? I can only recommend you start learning the basics of javascript or hire a developer to complete your project. This isn't a free programming service at your request.

Comment: where is your css and please make a http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: Having a bad day @NewToJS ?

Comment: @CarolMcKay Nope, my day is going just great. Thank you for asking :)

Comment: @NewToJS I have spent quite a long time trying to figure this out myself and having come up with no solution, felt it would be a good idea to ask an online community if they could help. My advice would be to not bother commenting if you are going to be negative, and get your facts straight before doing so

Comment: @Damo when asking for help it's very important to show that you have tried. Showing your attempts would do this and include any research you have done. Many people come to this website expecting people to do all the work for them this is why it's best you format and plan your question to the best you can.

Answer (score 0):

Put your separate css background images on these:

```
#aboutus {
 background-image:.....
}

#history {
 background-image:.....
}

#chef {
 background-image:.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code, all works fine and if you want change only contents background, `Carol McKay` wrote what you have to add in your code. You don't need in this case  any javascript code.
I created small example with your code and bootsrap classes: [jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/dd19895f/2/)
All gaps you can see depends bootstrap classes, for example, by default class `.alert` has:

```
.alert {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  ...
}
```

And one more example with content below `pills` and looks more familiar): [jsfiddle-link2](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/gck4za1y/)